# Dbus mainloop.h missing error

Tags: c, compiler-errors, dbus, low-level-api

I used

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs dbus-1` hello-serv.c  -o server
```

to compile a dbus program and getting error:

```
hello-serv.c:7:32: fatal error: dbus/dbus-mainloop.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I'm developing in C low level API.

I couldn't find the `mainloop.h` in any of the include directories.

Comment: Did you install the development files, e.g. `libdbus-1-dev` on Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm using fedora and there is no package named libdbus-1-dev in yum repositories . :(

Answer (score 0):

If dbus development files is installed correctly,
the installed dbus might be old
so that it does not have `dbus-mainloop.h`

If you have `yum`, try this to check dbus-mainloop.h is provided or not.

```
# yum provides '*/dbus-mainloop.h'
```

If it returns none, you should consult with dbus-document for corresponding version.